# Google Chrome display JSON AJAX response as tree and not as a plain text

Tags: ajax, json, google-chrome, view, tree

I cannot find an answer to this one:

My AJAX calls return JSON data. In Google Chrome Developer Tools > Resources > XHR when I click on the resource on the left and then on the Content tab I see the JSON string as a string and not as a tree as Firebug and Firebug Lite do.

How do I force Chrome to display it as a tree. Is there a Content-type that my PHP file must have???

Comment: @Matt McClure's answer below is the answer!

Comment: I have also had issues getting a tree structure when the strings are single quotes ' instead of double quotes ", changing ' to " helped

Comment: Firefox just shows json......

Answer (score 531):

To see a tree view in recent versions of Chrome:

Navigate to Developer Tools > Network > the given response > Preview

Comment: Totally glossed over the "Preview" tab and was looking at the "Response" tab. Thanks!

Comment: But i think to get this, you need to have the correct content-type.

Comment: Yes, you need a valid "application/json" content-type specified for chrome to give you the collapsible drop-down.

Comment: It is indeed a little less intuitive, because on the Headers tab they let us switch between "raw" and "parsed", so one would expect that they'd offer similar "parsed" view on the Response tab.

Comment: I wish it actually was JSON instead of a tree

Comment: After all these years... +1

Comment: it would be great to have the expand all, collapse, and source toggles.

Comment: you think they'd use a more reasonable and equally widely applicable name like "formatted" or "structured". "preview" doesn't say this feature at all.

Answer (score 74):

Google Chrome now supports this (`Developer Tools > Network > [XHR item in list] Preview`).

In addition, you can use a third party tool to format the json content.  [Here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)'s one that presents a tree view, and [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/)'s another that merely formats the text (and does validation).

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 11):

You can use Google Chrome Extension: `JSONView`
All formatted json result will be displayed directly on the browser.

Comment: OP asked specifically about json code shown inside dev tools.

Comment: Thank you ,Maybe this is not the perfect answer for the OP's question.But I was looking for this .Up voted

Answer (score 6):

The correct content-type for JSON data is `application/json`. I assume that is what you are missing.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't force Chrome to turn the JSON string into tree. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer:

You MUST encode your json like this: `{"c":21001,"m":"p"}` but not `{c:21001,m:"p"}` or `{'c':21001,'m':'p'}`

Thus, the key of a dict must be wrapped in double quotes:`"`, then chrome will preview it as json rather than plain text.

Comment: That's because the first one is valid JSON and the other examples are not (although they are valid javascript). See http://simonwillison.net/2006/oct/11/json/

Answer (score 2):

In order for it to display the JSON message properly it has to have the "application/json" mime type and to be correctly structured.

You can check the structure [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Chrome has added this feature since the last answer, but I was able to view the json response by...

- opening developer tools in the browser while on the page with the request
- submitting the request
- in developer tools - **"Console"** tab - click on the "Object" tree under the resource to expand

...I was able to view the response as a readable hierarchy that showed what to ask for and what is returned. (Neither Network or Resources tab had anything helpful that I was able to find.)

Happy requesting!

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with a build of Google Chrome Dev build 24.0.1312.5 that caused the preview panel to no longer display a json object tree but rather flat text. It should be fixed in the next dev

See more here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160733

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get Tree-view

See step by step instructions on how to do this in the below GIF. (I recorded in Chrome - chromium shouldn't be too different.)

Click on the link to enlarge and follow along

[image: How to get the tree view of the response in chrome]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Chrome Developer tools pretty print XHR content. See:
[Viewing HTML response from Ajax call through Chrome Developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181287/viewing-html-response-from-ajax-call-through-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome now has a button for pretty printing responses. Its the `{}` in the bottom left of the "Response" window:

[image: The toggle button]

Comment: I don't have this {} icon on my chrome, does it need a specific extension?