# Does Chrome's Dev Tools have a JSON explorer like Firebug's?

Tags: json, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

In Firebug, you can

> see JSON formatted as an expandable tree of items 
>   and also explore them using Firebug's Dom tab.
>   The view is available within Net panel and visible as 
>   soon as a JSON request is expanded.

As in this screenshot:

[image]

I'm trying to switch to Chrome but can't find this feature in Dev Tools.

**Does Chrome's Dev Tools provide something similar (assuming you're not using any additional extensions like Firebug Lite)?**

Comment: **Related/duplicate:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888454/google-chrome-display-json-ajax-response-as-tree-and-not-as-a-plain-text

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
inspect(myObject);
```

in the Chrome console to get an inline object inspector similar to what the DOM tab in Firebug gives you. In your case you can to do this on whatever object you assign your JSON results to.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know Chrome does not have this feature.

In case you didn't know, Firebug Lite for Chrome supports this feature (only for XHR requests), so you can use both Chrome Dev Tools and Firebug Lite to inspect JSON responses. See this blog post:

http://blog.getfirebug.com/2010/09/09/firebug-lite-1-3-1/

Disclaimer: I work with the Firebug Working Group

Answer (score 2):

**Chrome 12 (12.0.742.6) will have this feature!**

You can already [download the beta](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/chromium-rel-xp/) of 12 today.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20628#c4