# Google Chrome - Dev Tools - Network Tab - Preview - JSON vs. Text

Tags: google-chrome

I just updated Chrome to beta verstion - Version 24.0.1312.5 beta-m and the network tab preview used to show the tree view of a json response. Now it's plain text just like the response tab. I checked out the settings and nothing in there looked like it would change that back. Has anyone else seen this? And perhaps knows a fix or should I roll back to a previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with a build of Google Chrome Dev build 24.0.1312.5 that caused the preview panel to no longer display a json object tree but rather flat text. It should be fixed in the next dev build.

See more here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160733

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are looking for the "Preview" tab.
See this question: [Google Chrome display JSON AJAX response as tree and not as a plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3888454/266535)

Comment: The preview panel was the issue in the dev build that was no longer displaying the json object. See my original question when I explained that the preview panel was no longer showing the object but rather flat text just like the response tab.