# Force Chrome to show Json response formatted as tree structure

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, treeview

I can make my app to "force" Chrome (v 39.0.2171.99 m) to show `http` response as Json (instead of XML).

How do I get the Json in a **tree structure** (instead of a string)?

[Checking the Preview tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888454/google-chrome-display-json-ajax-response-as-tree-and-not-as-a-plain-text) in dev tools doesn't work for me.

I could paste the Json string into [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/), but I want to know a more direct route, if there is one.

Comment: Does using a <pre> tag help, or not ?

Comment: @XavierNorbal how would that help?

Comment: it always formatted me json strings so it was readable (I mean comprehensible)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh) (It's called JSON Viewer and the [source is available at github](https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer)) for years, it works great.

I don't know who's the developer is but if he ever reads this: Thanks for taking the time to develop such a timesaving tool!

Comment: The extension link is broken and blog post throwing a server error.

Comment: @SrdjanDonevski thanks for the heads up, answer updated. The old version was removed due to a vulnerability but there's a fork online, fixed and totally secure.