# Ajax add to compare error prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I got error in console log when i click button add to compare in prestashop 1.6 i don't know how to fix it can anyone help me please..!

[image]

http:my-url/index.phpindex.php?controller=products-comparison&ajax=1&action=add&id_product=34&_=1457661854862 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: `index.phpindex.php` - something wrong with your URL on that button.

Comment: thanks for help yes error with url

Comment: It's a bug in the JS file, it doesn't prepend '/' to the begging of ajax URL. I cant tell where is the bug because it was in version 1.6.0.9 or lowe as far as I remember

Comment: it ok i found it and fix it already in "\themes\your-theme-name\js\products-comparison.js"

Answer (score 0):

you can use tab network of developer tools in google chrome

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading

[Viewing HTML response from Ajax call through Chrome Developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181287/viewing-html-response-from-ajax-call-through-chrome-developer-tools)